# Wrong when use PrintWriter to write new HTML

Tags: java, servlets, printwriter

I used PrintWriter to do this code :

```
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Update Page</title>");
            out.println("</head>");

            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<center>");
            out.println("<h1>Please choose ID</h1>");
            out.println("</center>");
            out.println("<table width='359' border='1' align='center'>");
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td width='103'>ID:</td>");
            out.println("<th width='246'>");
            out.println("<select name='ID' id='ID' style='width:170px;' >");
            out.println("<option></option>");
            out.println("</select>");
            out.println("</th>");
            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>Name:</td>");
            out.println("<th><input type='text' name='Name' id='Name' style='width:170px;' /></th>");
            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>Address:</td>");
            out.println("<th><input type='text' name='Address' id='Address' style='width:170px;'/></th>");
            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println("<td>Email:</td>");
            out.println("<th><input type='text' name='Email' id='Email' style='width:170px;'/></th>");
            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>Phone Number:</td>");
            out.println("<th><input type='text' name='Phone' id='Phone' style='width:170px;'/></th>");
            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td></td>");
            //=================
            out.println("<td>");
            out.println("<div>");        
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='FillValue' value='Fill ID' style='float:left'/>");

            out.println("<form action='UpdateServlet' method='post'>");
            out.println("<input type='submid' name='Submid' value='Submit'  style='float:right'/>");
            out.println("</form>");
            out.println("</div>");
            out.println("</td>");
            out.println("</tr>");
            //==============
            out.println("</table>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
```

But something wrong when I click to Submid button, the result is :

HTTP Status 404 - /DungDV01852_Lab1_2_3/UpdateServlet

type Status report

message /DungDV01852_Lab1_2_3/UpdateServlet

description The requested resource (/DungDV01852_Lab1_2_3/UpdateServlet) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.29

I Have class updateServlet.
Another : I have the HTML :

```
            <td>
                <div>
                    <form action="FillServlet" method="post">
       <input type="submit" name="FillValue" value="Fill ID" style="float:left"/>
                    </form>
    <input type="submit" name="Submid" id="Submid" value="Submit"style="float:right"/>
                </div>
            </td>
```

It Run exactly, but the same when I use PrintWriter to write a new HTML is Wrong. Please help me. Thanks everyone

Comment: Don't do this. Use servlets for your Java code, and JSP/JSF/some other templating or HTML generation for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: In your first case,  input type is "submid"...I believe its a typo.

Comment: I have to use PrintWriter to do this code . It is my homework :(. thank you but I can not use JSP/JSF/some other

Comment: - provide web.xml so we can see why you are getting a 404
- <input type="submit" ...>
- all of your <select>s and <input>s should be contained by a <form> element.

Comment: Check whether you have servlet mappings in place inside your web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question will not cause a `404` error.  A `404` will happens either because your code explicitly sets a 404 response by calling `response.sendError(...)`, or because the request never made it to your servlet in the first place.  And the most likely cause of the latter is that your `web.xml` file is not configuring and mapping your servlet properly.

If you want more help, please add the entire `web.xml` file to the Question.